# Azure function not able to recognize Get-AzADApplication

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I have created a azure function where i am trying to execute the code `Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName cs-sp-aro-testrotation`

when i run i get the error as
the term 'Get-AzADApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

I am pasting my whole azure function code please tell me how to do same

```
 using namespace System.Net
   
    # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
    param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
    
    # Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
    Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
    
    # Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
    $name = $Request.Query.Name
    if (-not $name) {
        $name = $Request.Body.Name
    }
    Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName cs-sp-aro-testrotation
    $body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
    
    if ($name) {
        Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName cs-sp-aro-testrotation
        $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    }
    
    # Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
    Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body = $body
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the function app in the portal -> `App files` -> `requirements.psd1`, make sure you have installed the `Az` powershell module(for newly created apps, this line will be commented by default, if so, just uncomment it).

```
@{ 
    'Az' = '5.*'
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Of course you need to login, by default it will login with the [MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) of your function app automatically as shown in the `profile.ps1`.

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

To let `Get-AzADApplication` work fine, there are also other steps you need to do.

1.Navigate to the `Identity` in the portal -> enable the system-assigned MSI like below.

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> search for `Directory readers` -> click it -> `Add assignments` -> add the MSI as a `Directory readers` role(just search for your function app name).

[image]

Then run `Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName xxxx`, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank i did that now when i try to run the command ERROR: No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.Exception So is it no possible to get the sp details without login from azure function as azure function runs inside the portal

Comment: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.HResult. I am trying to now login with service principal but it says connect-azureid is not recognized

Comment: @ashish It means you didn't install `AzureAD` module, add `'AzureAD' = '2.0.2.4'` in `requirements.psd1`. Besides, stackoverflow avoid ask several questions in one post, if you have any other questions, please ask it in another post.